# Is it really much cheaper for an Australian to get a Chinese visa in Malaysia than in Australia?

Tags: visas, china, fees-and-charges, malaysia, australian-citizens

I'm flying to Malaysia in about a week and a half and would like to obtain a multiple-entry Chinese visa at some point so I can use The Middle Kingdom as a hub to visit several neighbouring countries.

I'm pushing it close but I probably have enough time to get a visa here in Australia before I leave, but I thought it might be easier to get it while I'm in Kuala Lumpur with less time pressure.

In my experience so far I had found that countries generally have a set price for visas depending only on the nationality of the applicant (though things like processing fees might vary). But in trying to compare online the application process in Sydney to that in Kuala Lumpur, it seems the visa I want would cost about double if I applied at home. Am I reading this right?

(I'm looking at the six month multiple entry visa specifically.)

- [Chinese visa fee schedule for Australia](http://www.visaforchina.org/webrms/wwwroot/SYD_EN/upload/Attach/mrbj/262540.pdf) (120 + 38.50 Australian dollars ~ $158.60 `AUD`)
- [Chinese visa fee schedule for Malaysia](http://www.visaforchina.org/KUL_EN/visainstruction/250782.shtml) (250 + 28 Malaysian ringgit ~ $94.50 `AUD`)

Answer (score 5):

It seems like you read it right.

Using the simplest logic a man can have:

```
$158.60 > $94.50
```

Therefore, the second option (get the Chinese visa in Malaysia) is the cheaper option. Anyway I would prefer paying the extra dollars and do it at home, they may ask for a document or something which you don't have while abroad.

Comment: Well if they make it difficult I'll just ase KL as my travel hub. No visa hassles there and it's the home of Air Asia (-;